# Twitter bootstrap nav in asp.net application active class?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter bootstrap in an asp.net application and below is my code for the navbar:

```
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="brand" href="../">MyApp</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="../">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../About.aspx">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../ContactUs.aspx">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I would like to change the active menu item each time I am on a page that links to the menu item. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Toby Jones indeed suggests a good helper method. However, some people might want to select menu items only by Controller and others might want to get menu items selected by the combination of a controller and action. The solution mentioned in the article referred by Toby only takes care of the second scenario.

Library [TwitterBootstrapMvc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc) covers both situations with the following syntax:

```
@using (var nav = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Nav().SetLinksActiveByControllerAndAction()))
{
    @nav.ActionLink("Link 1", MVC.Account.SomeAction())
    @nav.ActionLink("Link 2", "SomeOtherAction")
}
```

Mthod `.SetLinksActiveByControllerAndAction()` could be replaced by method `.SetLinksActiveByController()` which would work for the first scenario.

It is also worth mentioning that the same extension methods are available on DropDowns:

```
@using (var dd = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new DropDown("Some Trigger").SetLinksActiveByController()))
{
    @dd.ActionLink("Some link", "action")
}
```

Comment: The aricle has been deleted, could you explain "MVC.Account.SomeAction()" further?

Comment: BMVC supports [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/). Look into it and you'll understand

Answer (score 5):

With JavaScript, You can get the current path using the code below:

```
var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
```

and add the active class to the current item like this:

```
$(".menu a[href='" + currentPath + "']").parent().addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 2):

See here for an excellent helper class:

http://chrisondotnet.com/2012/08/setting-active-link-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.