# Switch active tab with Bootstrap's Navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap's navbar for a website. I've separated the navbar into its own HTML page. When any page is loaded, it will load the navbar.html page with JQuery. When a user clicks on say, page2, the "Home" link is still shown as active when it should be "Page2".

Is there a simple way to switch the class for the page2 link to "active" using javascript, jquery or bootstrap magic?

navbar.html

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#l">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">page3</a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery on page2

```
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        $('#nav').load('nav.html');
    });

    jQuery(function(){
        $('.nav a:contains("page2")').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.nav a:contains("page2")').addClass('active');
```

Or, to add the class to the parent element (`li`):

```
$('.nav a:contains("page2")').parent().addClass('active');
```

**Live Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/BDTnj/

Comment: I added this to page2 and it didn't work. I also tried $(".nav li:contains('page2')").addClass("active"); no success..

Comment: @thedeepfield i updated my answer, had an errant space in between the `a` and the `:` ...

Comment: its not working for me. could it be because i have my nav bar loaded from a separate html file?

Comment: it works when I put the code into the nav.html. so it has to do with having my nav loaded separated from the page.

Comment: @thedeepfield look at my example, the code is there and working. make sure you're executing it at the right time/event like `jQuery.ready`

Answer (score 2):

Use this: `$('.nav a:contains("page2")').tab('show');`

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was that the navbar content was being loaded as a separate file onto page2 and the .addClass was on page2. it could not find the html tags. In order to get the navbar to show the active link, I put `$('.nav a:contains("page2")').parent().addClass('active');` with my code to load the navbar:

Page2:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    $('#nav').load('nav.html', function() {
        $('.nav a:contains("Home")').parent().addClass('active');
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I'm using Backbone with Bootstrap, and here's my solution (with variables renamed for clarity):

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    '':                 'list',
    'menu-items/new':   'itemForm',
    'menu-items/:item': 'itemDetails',
    'orders':           'orderItem',
    'orders/:item':     'orderItem'
},

initialize: function  () {
    // [snip]

    this.firstView = new FirstView();
    this.secondView = new SecondView();
    this.thirdView = new ThirdView();

    this.navMenu = {
        firstViewMenuItem:  $('li#first-menu-item'),
        secondViewMenuItem: $('li#second-menu-item'),
        thirdViewMenuItem:  $('li#third-menu-item'),
        reset:              function() {
            _.each(this, function(menuItem) {
                if (!_.isFunction(menuItem) && menuItem.hasClass('active')) {
                    menuItem.removeClass('active');
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return this;
        }
    };
},
// [snip]
```

Within my router callbacks, I remove any existing 'active' menu classes and set the selected to 'active', e.g.,

```
// [snip]
list: function () {
    $('#app').html(this.firstView.render().el);
    this.navMenu.reset().firstViewMenuItem.addClass('active');
},
// [snip]
```

Answer (score -1):

in case your server side technology is `asp.net-mvc`, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017493/twitter-bootstrap-nav-in-asp-net-application-active-class/17580669#17580669) useful.